# How to ensure get label for zero counts in python pandas pd.cut

Tags: pandas, ipython

I am analyzing a DataFrame and getting timing counts which I want to put into specific buckets (0-10 seconds, 10-30 seconds, etc).

Here is a simplified example:

```
import pandas as pd

filter_values = [0, 10, 20, 30]  # Bucket Values for pd.cut

#Sample Times
df1 = pd.DataFrame([1, 3, 8, 20], columns  = ['filtercol'])

#Use cut to get counts for each bucket
out = pd.cut(df1.filtercol, bins = filter_values)
counts = pd.value_counts(out)
print counts
```

The above prints:

```
(0, 10]     3
(10, 20]    1
dtype: int64
```

You will notice it does not show any values for (20, 30].  This is a problem because I want to put this into my output as zero.  I can handle it using the following code:

```
bucket1=bucket2=bucket3=0
if '(0, 10]' in counts: 
    bucket1=counts['(0, 10]']
if '(10, 20]' in counts: 
    bucket2=counts['(10, 30]']
if '(20, 30]' in counts: 
    bucket3=counts['(30, 60]']
print bucket1, bucket2, bucket3
```

But I want a simpler cleaner approach where I can use:

```
print counts['(0, 10]'], counts['(10, 30]'], counts['(30, 60]']
```

Ideally where the print is based on the values in filter_values so they are only in one place in the code. Yes I know I can change the print to use filter_values[0]...

Lastly when using cut is there a way to specify infinity so the last bucket is all values greater than say 60?

Cheers,
Stephen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [reindex](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.reindex.html) by the categorical's levels:

```
In [11]: pd.value_counts(out).reindex(out.levels, fill_value=0)
Out[11]: 
(0, 10]     3
(10, 20]    1
(20, 30]    0
dtype: int64
```